# SQL Server 2008 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I'm having an issue in SQL Server I've been trying to debug for quite some time now and I can't figure out where the problem is.

If I run this query…

```
SELECT 
    CAST(Hotel_Id AS bigint) AS Hotel_Id, 
    Hotel_Name, 
    CAST(Room_Category AS bigint) AS Room_Category, 
    Room_Category_Name, 
    CAST(Room_Type AS bigint) AS Room_Type, 
    Room_Type_Name, 
    Info_URL_Title, 
    Info_URL , 
    MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS bigint)) AS Price_Excl_VAT, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS bigint)) = 0 
        THEN 0 ELSE MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS bigint)) - MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS bigint)) 
    END AS VAT,
    MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS bigint)) AS Price,
    MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Dep_Amount, 0) AS [bigint])) AS Dep_Amount  
FROM 
    uvw_HotelAllotmentToBook 
WHERE Client_Id = 'CLIENT' AND Project_Id = 'PROJECT' 
    AND Allotment_Date >= '2014-05-11' AND Allotment_Date < '2014-05-14' 
GROUP BY Hotel_Id, Hotel_Name, Room_Category, Room_Category_Name, Room_Type, Room_Type_Name, Info_URL_Title, Info_URL, Dep_Amount
HAVING COUNT(Allotment_Date) >= 3
```

In for example one project that we have a bit over 4000 records it keeps giving me this error

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

I've been googling around but can't find a way to fix this, I tried as you can see casting all number fields to big int with no luck.

I need to find the MAX of the prices because the price per night can change.

UPDATE

```
SELECT Hotel_Id
   ,Hotel_Name
   ,Room_Category AS Room_Category
   ,Room_Category_Name
   ,Room_Type AS Room_Type
   ,Room_Type_Name
   ,Info_URL_Title
   ,Info_URL
   ,COUNT(Allotment_Date)
   ,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Price_Excl_VAT
   ,CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT)) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS BIGINT)) - MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT))
    END AS VAT
   ,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Price
   ,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Dep_Amount, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Dep_Amount
FROM uvw_HotelAllotmentToBook
WHERE Client_Id = 'PCWHK'
    AND Project_Id = 'INTA14'
    AND Allotment_Date >= '2014-05-11'
    AND Allotment_Date < '2014-05-14'
GROUP BY Hotel_Id
   ,Hotel_Name
   ,Room_Category
   ,Room_Category_Name
   ,Room_Type
   ,Room_Type_Name
   ,Info_URL_Title
   ,Info_URL
   --,Dep_Amount
HAVING COUNT(Allotment_Date) >= 3
```

I keep getting the same the overflow error but the moment I comment out this line

```
   ,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Dep_Amount, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Dep_Amount
```

The error is gone.

The problem is that I need the Dep_Amount in the result.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How about some real data (a row from your database that you know fails)? The table schema would be nice, too. `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.` sounds like maybe you have a floating point number that exceeds the allowable big int?

Comment: It only fails when it's a "lot" of records. With a small project it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Remove columns one at a time until you find the troublemaker. Then inspect the values in that column for the range of rows you are handling. For handling pricing you may need to use a datatype with a larger range, e.g. NUMERIC. You may want to use COALESCE( MAX( Column ), 0 ) rather than casting.

Comment: Price is an integer?  Does it work without that `CASE` statement?

Comment: @FedericoGiust what data type is `Dep_Amount` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem!

The problem was in the view.

On this line where it was generating the Dep_Amount column

```
CASE 
WHEN COALESCE(hap.Charge_Dep_Amount, 0) = 0 
THEN COALESCE(hap.Dep_Amount, 0) 
ELSE (COALESCE(CAST(hap.Dep_Amount AS numeric), 0) * COALESCE(CAST(hap.Price AS numeric), 0)) / 10000 
END AS Dep_Amount,
```

Now that I'm casting the else as numeric the error is gone!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast columns that are just being returned without any operations performed on them. I would run query in the following way and just uncomment one line at the time to figure out where the problem is. It is likely that very last line `HAVING COUNT(` is what is breaking

```
SELECT Hotel_IdAS Hotel_Id
   ,Hotel_Name
   ,Room_Category AS Room_Category
   ,Room_Category_Name
   ,Room_Type AS Room_Type
   ,Room_Type_Name
   ,Info_URL_Title
   ,Info_URL
   ,COUNT(Allotment_Date)
   --,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Price_Excl_VAT
   --,CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT)) = 0 THEN 0
   --      ELSE MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS BIGINT)) - MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price_Excl_VAT, 0) AS BIGINT))
   -- END AS VAT
   --,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Price, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Price
   --,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Dep_Amount, 0) AS [bigint])) AS Dep_Amount
FROM uvw_HotelAllotmentToBook
WHERE Client_Id = 'CLIENT'
    AND Project_Id = 'PROJECT'
    AND Allotment_Date >= '2014-05-11'
    AND Allotment_Date < '2014-05-14'
GROUP BY Hotel_Id
   ,Hotel_Name
   ,Room_Category
   ,Room_Category_Name
   ,Room_Type
   ,Room_Type_Name
   ,Info_URL_Title
   ,Info_URL
   ,Dep_Amount
--HAVING COUNT(Allotment_Date) >= 3
```

Comment: OP indicates 4000 records in the table, so `COUNT()` shouldn't be causing an overflow.

Comment: I pasted the query exactly as you posted here and still gives me the same error. If I only comment out this line ,MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Dep_Amount, 0) AS [bigint])) AS Dep_Amount it works, the moment I remove the comment from that line I start getting the same error.

Comment: so it works with that line but does not work without it?